Is greater risk and volatility a characteristic of lower-priced equity?
I read the following from here:

When it comes to risk, low-priced stocks possess high risk compared to
high-priced stocks. The primary reason for low-priced stocks being
highly risky is they are traded infrequently. They have been actively
present in the stock market for a long time but may be performing
poorly. Hence they are available to investors at a low price. Due to
this, it increases their risk factor. On the other hand, high-priced
stocks are less risky due to their reputation and market
capitalization. Hence they are considered safe for investment.
Volatility means fluctuating the average price of the stock. The
low-priced stocks are cheaper, and hence they are considered highly
volatile. Naturally, they have higher to fall rapidly in price because
they rise and fall in a short span and frequently. Hence, investors
looking for security and stable stocks don’t prefer low-priced stocks.

Is it true? Does price correlate strongly with volatility and trading-frequency?  Does it apply to ETFs and mutual funds?
I also found this article of relevance.  It seems to agree with the sentiment, but if you observe the chart the standard deviation (volatility) for stocks below $2.50 is dramatic, while above that price is tampered down.

Yes there is (inverse) correlation between price and volatility. Most healthy companies do not trade at low prices (e.g. less than $2). Companies ideally want to trade at somewhat higher prices (like $10-$100), but not too high because it reduces liquidity (not many people can buy 100 shares of a $500 stock). Which is why companies (like NVIDIA recently) do splits to reduce their share price.
Most often, these low-price stocks are companies that at one point traded at higher prices and have dropped over time due to poor performance. Also, volatility is a relative measure, so stocks that are trading at low prices don't take as much change to have much higher volatility relative to their price.  A 50 cent move for a $1 stock is huge - for AAPL it's nothing.
Finally, there is a much greater chance (relative to higher price stocks) that these stocks will go to zero, and much higher chance that they will break out and increase many times over.  So it's somewhat reasonable to have higher volatility for lower price stocks given that "extreme" changes either way are far more likely.
I'm not sure I agree with all of the assertions in the article (volatility is not the only reason traders tend to stay away from low-price stocks) but there is a correlation.

Does it apply to ETFs and mutual funds?

Not as much, because by design they are much less volatile due to their diversification. It would take a catastrophic collapse of an entire sector (since funds are typically targeted to at least a market segment) for funds to collapse.  Some companies in a fund may be highly volatile, but it would be unusual for all stocks in a fund to be volatile at the same time.
Plus, ETFs and Funds are traded more in partial lots than individual stocks, so there's less concern about the actual price than there is with stocks.

On Correlation, Causation, and Rule of Thumbs
There is no causal relationship between the price of a stock, and its volatility or risk. During an IPO, a company more or less define at which price it wishes to introduce its shares. Consider that "Berkshire Hathaway Inc. class A" shares trade today at around $627,400. Stock splits are a thing, so the share price could be brought lower by splitting, but instead the price is "artificially" maintained high.
The lack of causation does not prevent the apparition of correlation between a stock's low price, volatility, and risks, out of which a rule of thumb can be formulated to help investors quickly sort out stocks in a first pass assessment.
I would take the given advice you've read as a rule of thumb. It may not always hold true, but as per the study you reference, it does appear to hold true often enough that it's worth its pound of salt.
Liquidity Bonus
A point addressed in the quote is liquidity, which refers to how much a stock trades.
In general, the best indicator of the market value of a stock is the price at which it trades: unlike guesses, forecasts, etc... a trade means that a buyer and seller both agreed on the value at which to trade.
Illiquid stocks, by virtue of not trading (or not trading much), make it harder to assess their market value. This increases the risk associated with them, since taking trading decisions is hard, when not being able to assess their fair value.
Illiquid stocks are also risky in the same way as real estate is. If there's only a single share bought or sold every day, and you'd like to sell a hundred shares... you'll have a hard time doing so. You'll either have to accept to liquidate your shares slowly -- so as to not impact the price -- or to accept a lower price for them.
Thus, regardless of low/high volatility, an absence of liquidity increases risk. If your shares represent a significant fraction of the daily traded volume, be prepared not get their fair value when you sell.
